# Laravel return different timestamp from database using eloquent

Tags: postman, laravel-9, php-8.1

I'm using

Laravel Framework 9.37.0

PHP 8.1.10

Using postman for get and add data

I try to get data from MySQL database using eloquent

```
$investment = Investment::where('user_id', $user_id)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();
return $investment;
```

That code return different timestamp from my database

### This is timestamp from my database

created_at = 2022-11-01 11:26:55

updated_at = 2022-11-01 11:26:55

### But this is timestamp from my postman

created_at = 2022-11-01 04:26:55

updated_at = 2022-11-01 04:26:55

**Result is different 7 Hours**. I Already set my config/app.php "timezone" to "Asia/Jakarta". I try to set in UTC and return different timestamp too

This is my model

```
class Investment extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $casts = [
        'created_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d H:i:s',
        'updated_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d H:i:s',
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'user_id');
    }

    public function plan()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(PlanList::class, 'plan_id');
    }
}
```

Timestamp is correct when I add data, it is only wrong when I GET data. But if using DB::table()... timestamp is correct.

Can someone explain **why this returns a different timestamp when using eloquent?**

I try to change timezone to UTC but still return different timestamp.

Comment: Can u share the solution? I face the same problem. Thanks before

Comment: Set serializeDate in the model as shown by Mohammed Reza

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let me explain what happen.

When you return eloquent instance to a JSON response (API or something else), the Carbon instance will always convert in the ISO-8601 string and given in GMT timezone, as it's the standard and very recommended way to exchange date information between systems.

**First set timezone and then try this ways:**

**1. Using DATE_FORMAT**

```
$investment =Investment::select('user_id' , DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s") as created_on'))->get(); 
return $investment;
```

**NOTE:** don't use created_at as the alias name, because the result will be the same!

**2. Using serializeDate in your model:**

```
class Investment extends Model{

use HasFactory;
use DateTimeInterface;

protected function serializeDate(DateTimeInterface $date)
{
    return $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
}

public function plan()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(PlanList::class, 'plan_id');
}
}
```

**Note:** #2 is a clear way and doesn't need to change the column's name!

I hope these ways help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You must set your time zone in the config\app.php file
If you have set your time zone inside the file, this will only happen on your side, but if you define it in the config file with return, your problem will be solved.

ex:

'timezone' => 'Asia/Jakarta',

Comment: I Already set my config/app.php "timezone" to "Asia/Jakarta" but it's not work. But I already find the solution

Comment: Lol.. She's already set